# MATLAB convert from struct to table and ouput as csv

Tags: matlab, csv, image-processing

As part of an image processing pipeline using 'regionprops' in Matlab I generate the struct:

```
vWFfeatures = 


1631x1 struct array with fields:

Area
Centroid
MajorAxisLength
MinorAxisLength
Eccentricity
EquivDiameter
```

Where 'Centroid' is a Vector containing [x, y] for example [12.4, 26.2]. I would like to convert this struct to a table and save as a CSV file. The objective is to separate the 'Centroid' vector into two columns in the table labelled Centroid_X and Centroid_Y for example. I am not sure how to achieve this.

So far I have investigated using the 'struct2table' function. This ouputs the 'Centroid' as one column. In addition when I try to assign the output to a variable I get an error:

```
table = struct2table(vWFfeatures)
Error using struct2table
Too many output arguments.
```

I cannot understand this, any help please?

Comment: Have you tried `'AsArray',true` as additional arguments to `struct2table`? Your struct looks like it might have uncompatible dimensions.

Comment: Yes I have tried this and no it doesn't work. I think the problem maybe in the struct2table version, since I am running Matlab R2013a this function was not available so I downloaded it: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36214-struct2table but the documentation is different from what I was reading. I still get the error too many ouput arguments

Comment: Yeah, that one's a user submission, that's not the original `struct2table` included in later MATLAB builds. The version you linked to does not support output arguments, which means you can't assign the result to a variable. You'll have to either find a version matching the official behavior or re-write the one you downloaded to include this functionality.

Comment: So this functionality is not included in Matlab R2013a by default?

Comment: Since it doesn't have `struct2table`, no. There might be a way to get the same result by a default function, but writing one yourself shouldn't be too hard. I'm writing up a few hints right now, give me a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it in the end: extracted each field from struct used horzcat to join into a new array then defined headers and used csvwrite_with_headers, to ouput to csv.

```
wpbFeatures = regionprops(vWFlabelled, 'Area','Centroid', 'MajorAxisLength', 'MinorAxisLength', 'Eccentricity', 'EquivDiameter');
wpbArea = vertcat(wpbFeatures.Area);
wpbCentroid = vertcat(wpbFeatures.Centroid);
wpbCentroidX = wpbCentroid(:,1);
wpbCentroidY = wpbCentroid(:,2);
wpbFeret = max(imFeretDiameter(vWFlabelled, linspace(0,180,201)), [], 2);
wpbMajorAxisLength = vertcat(wpbFeatures.MajorAxisLength);
wpbMinorAxisLength = vertcat(wpbFeatures.MinorAxisLength);
wpbEccentricity = vertcat(wpbFeatures.Eccentricity);
wpbEquivDiameter = vertcat(wpbFeatures.EquivDiameter);
wpbFeatures = horzcat(wpbArea, wpbCentroidX, wpbCentroidY, wpbFeret, wpbMajorAxisLength, wpbMinorAxisLength, wpbEccentricity, wpbEquivDiameter);
headers = {'Area','CentroidX','CentroidY', 'Feret', 'MajorAxisLength', 'MinorAxisLength', 'Eccentricity', 'EquivDiameter'};
csvwrite_with_headers(strcat(PlateName, '_ResultsFeatures.csv'),wpbFeatures,headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the original `struct2table` isn't available to you, you might want to implement specifically the behavior you're trying to achieve yourself.
In this case, this means extracting the values you want to save, (split the array,) then save the data:

```
data_Centroid = vertcat(vWFfeatures.Centroid); %// contains the centroid data
Centroid_X = data_Centroid(:,1); %// The first column is X
Centroid_Y = data_Centroid(:,2); %// the second column is Y
csvwrite('centroid.csv',data_Centroid); %// writes values into csv
```

If you want column headers in your csv, it gets complicated because csvwrite can only handle numeric arrays:

```
celldata = num2cell(num2str(data_Centroid)); %// create cell array
celldata(:,3) = celldata(:,4); %// copy col 4 (y data) into col 3 (spaces)
for i=1:length(celldata)
    celldata{i,2} = ','; %// col 2 has commas
    celldata{i,4} = '\n'; %// col 4 has newlines
end
celldata = celldata'; %'// transpose to make the entries come columnwise
strdata = ['Centroid_X,Centroid_Y\n',celldata{:}]; %// contains all as string

fid = fopen('centroid.csv','w'); % writing the string into the csv
fprintf(fid,strdata);
fclose(fid);
```